# mysql "boolean given" without mysql errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the error

```
connected
`Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`
```

I know that means there's a problem with de sql provided, but sql is fine and I can't get it to print the error. are there other ways?

my full code:

```
<?php include "inc/config.php"; ?>
<?php include "inc/funciones.php"; ?>
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
<?php 

if(mysql_select_db($db_db2)){
    echo "connected<br>";
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM trabajo limit 5';
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$result = mysql_query($query);

try {
    while($estado = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $query  = 'UPDATE trabajo set estadoActual=(SELECT nombreTarea FROM 
                     tareastrabajo where 
                     numeroEntrada = "'.$estado["numeroEntrada"].'" 
                     AND fechaCompletada is not null 
                     order by fechaCompletada DESC limit 1) 
                     where numeroEntrada="'.$estado["numeroEntrada"].'"';
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $result = mysql_query($query);

    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "---";
    echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

As you can see, the connection is fine, so no problems there.
I also tried the classic

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

But same result.

DISCLAIMER:
Please avoid answers and comments pointing out about mysqli or PDO.
I inderstand the issues myself and we're in the process of migrating it.
Meanwhile, we have to deal with this.

EDIT: THANKS! I WAS OVERRIDING $result. What a lame way to waste half my morning...

Comment: You override `$result` in your while loop. Use a different variable.

Comment: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: bub, thanks for reading the bottom disclaimer

Comment: @bub OP mentioned about it. Read it.

Comment: If it throws that error during the first iteration of the while loop, then it's due to no results being available (either no rows returned or a malformed query). If it does it after the first iteration, then as @JonStirling pointed out, it's because you've overwritten the $result variable that you are fetching from.

Comment: @b0s3 You must never allow anyone to order you to be quiet, you must always speak your mind my friend ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Jon Stirling's comment you have overwritten the `$result` variable with the results of an `UPDATE` statement in the first iteration of the while loop.

Thus the error occurs on the second visit to the condition

```
while ($estado = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

This boolean is being passed back in to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` causing the exception.. there is no mysql error.

In response to Geoff Atkin's comment.. no rows returned should be handled fine by `mysql_fetch_assoc()`